# Is there an issue with dkms and kernels greater than 4.17?

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, 18.10

I am using Xubuntu 18.10 64bit and was trying to get a new higher speed usb wifi adapter working.

I assumed the more modern a kernel the better chance of the adapter being supported without having to play with extra drivers etc. but I found to get dkms to build a module that the kernel could see required stepping down from the latest and greatest to 4.17 before it would work.

This is the device:

```
Device 002: ID 0bda:8812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8812AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WLAN Adapter
```

Has there been changes to `dkms` or module formats recently that have roll into more modern kernels?

**Edit 1:**

Error coming back from `dkms` trying to add the modules:

```
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.
Skipping... 
Building module: cleaning build area... 
'make' all KVER=4.19.13-041913-generic........(bad exit status: 2) 
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8812au: 4.2.2 not found Error! 
Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.19.13-041913- generic (x86_64) Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.2.2/build/make.log for more information.
```

Comment: `4.17` is no longer being maintained. `4.14` and `4.19` are Long Term Support (LTS) kernels that will be maintained for five years. The latest kernel is `4.20`. Do you have a link to the kernel you downloaded and installed? Can you update your question with `dkms` error messages whilst installing?

Comment: sudo dkms build rtl8812au/4.2.2

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' all KVER=4.19.13-041913-generic........(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8812au: 4.2.2 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.19.13-041913-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.2.2/build/make.log for more information.

Comment: Can you edit your question and put your comments inside it? That way you or I can format the output nicely.

Comment: @ WinEunuuchs2Unix

This is the error coming back from dkms trying to add the modules:  
  
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...  
  
Building module:  
cleaning build area...  
'make' all KVER=4.19.13-041913-generic........(bad exit status: 2)  
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8812au: 4.2.2 not found  
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.19.13-041913-  generic (x86_64)  
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.2.2/build/make.log for more   information.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I've copy and pasted your comment up into your question so others can see it formatted nicely and read it more easily. Personally I haven't run into this error but I'm not using Realtek hardware.

Comment: The kernel you are using is unofficial and unsupported, and clearly not compatible with this driver. If the driver was installed from the official 18.10 repositories, it should work with the 4.18 kernel from there.

Comment: Well I stated I was unable to install with above 4.17. With 4.18 kernel UKUU was unable to download the last three revisions of the kernel so I counted it as a fail on general principles.